# Part 2 - How can I responsively place a link over an image that stays in place even though the screens change?

Tags: html, css

**The following was my first post -** 
I am attempting to overlay a link over a div background image, but would like the link to stay in place as I test screen widths by taking the mouse and narrowing the screen. The URL is http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/index2.html. As you can see where the "a link here" is where I would like the link to be and stays there. It seems to me that there has to be a better way than the way I set up the txt-link class.

**The script and bit of code shown below is the response that I received.**  The script works great I believe - recenters the text. But there seems to be problem with something somewhere - not sure.  First off, on my laptop, the top and right placement seems to be off.  But when I start minimizing the screen to see if the text re-positions itself, it works great.  The ipad2 that I am using is another problem.  I pull the site up in landscape, the text is off center,  I rotate ipad to portrait, the text looks great, then back to landscape, now text is center beautifully.  On my samsung 5 phone, same thing, except that I have to refresh the screen to get the text to display.  on a larger desktop monitor, the first time I pull up the site, the "a link here" text is over the banner that runs across the image.  Not sure what is going on here? Is is a refreshing issue?  Also how can I adjust the top and right attributes?

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function(){

    $image = $("#image");
    $link = $("#linkContent");

    imageTop = $image.offset().top;
    imageLeft = $image.offset().top;
    imageWidth = $image.width();
    imageHeight = $image.height();
    linkWidth = $link.width()/2;
    linkHeight = $link.height()/2;

    $link.offset({top:(imageTop+imageHeight)/2 - linkHeight,left:(imageWidth+imageLeft)/2 - linkWidth});
})
</script> 


 <img id="image" class="fixed" src="images/RFYL-MainPageBanner.jpg">
 <div id="linkContent" style="font-size: 25px; 
       color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; z-index: 2; 
       top: 510px; left: 734px;">
   <div>a link here</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you place the link just in CSS? Can you show an image of the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to have the text center aligned, why not just use pure CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/73rebh4c/

CSS:

```
#img-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#img-container img{
    width: 100%;   
}

#text-container{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;   
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

MARKUP

```
<div id="img-container">
    <img id="image" src="http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/images/RFYL-MainPageBanner.jpg">
    <div id="text-container">a link here</div>
</div>
```

What is happening?

The image is contained within a DIV with position relative, the image will fill up the container (using width 100%). As the image increases in width, it will force the containing div to match its height.

The text is positioned absolutely to the div. Using top 50%, it will center vertically. The line-height and margin-top is to make sure the text is absolutely center (instead of starting from the center and filling up downwards). We center horizontally by using text-align: center.

Comment: I believe this will work with no problems tribe84!  I will build of the logic by creating a link with a colored background.  thanks so much!!!